# Google analatyics GA4 records are not cleared after sending Data delete request

Tags: google-analytics

I have sent a data delete request in GA4 account for some date period, and the request status is showing as completed. But when I check the Monetisation reports it's still showing the value of the event elements. I have attached the screenshots of the delete request and report view. how to remove those values from the reports.if some have an idea please share with me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE8Jh.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u44kc.jpg

How to remove GA4 records value from the reports